# Evaluate smooth.spline at specific point in R

Tags: r, interpolation, splines

In **R**, I'm using **smooth.spline {stats}** function to fit a spline through some function values.

```
x=seq(0, 1,0.01)
y=sin(x*23) - 0.6*cos(x*7)
plot(x,y)
ss= smooth.spline(x=x, y=y, df=35)
plot(ss)
```

Now *ss* object contains all the values of the fitted spline required to draw and evaluate the spline at any given point.

```
ss$fit
$knot
[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000    1.0000000

$nk
[1] 6

$min
[1] 1

$range
[1] 3

$coef
[1] 0.5549946 0.4366268 0.1988102 1.1388495 0.7444880 0.5479000

attr(,"class")
[1] "smooth.spline.fit"
```

How can I use the coefficients and knots from the *ss$fit* object to compute the value of the spline function at a point xa.
I know I can use predict but I would like to actually compute the value manually.

My attempt is described in the following function which is not producing the expected results:

```
estimateSpline <- function(xv, fit){
    knots = unique(fit$knot)
    knots = knots[ 2 : (length(knots)-1) ]
    len = length(knots)

    xv = (xv - fit$min) / fit$range

    Gbase = rep(xv, len )
    Gbase = Gbase - knots
    Gbase[Gbase < 0] = 0
    Gbase = c(rep(xv,4), Gbase)

    Gpow = c(seq(0, 3, 1), rep (3, len))
    Gvec = Gbase ^ Gpow
    res = fit$coef %*% Gvec
    return (res)
}
```

I understand the theory behind splines and I read a lot of documents about the math behind it.

Can anyone help me evaluate the value of the fitted spline function at any arbitrary point *xv*?

I don't fully comprehend the data format, number and order of the parameters outputted by smooth.spline so that I can reconstruct the *predict* function's results.

Thanks

Comment: So what's the question here? Why don't you trust `predict.smooth.spline` ? It does exactly what you seem to be grasping for.  If you want help debugging your home-brew "predict" function there, then please post what you think the result should be, and why.

Comment: My end goal is to be able to "export" the function i'm fitting with the spline, from R, to excel or an imperative programming language. I want to be able to evaluate in say _java_ any point x on the spline. In java I don't have _predict_ but I can use the math behind it. So how do I do this?

Comment: The calculations are done by `predict.smooth.spline.fit` which actually uses a Fortran routine, `bvalus` which, in turn, calls `bvalue`. You can see the code, with commentary, for this here: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/bvalue.f